# Converting raw binary to float printing 0 for small values

Tags: floating-point, intel, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I am trying to read 2 32 bit values ( assuming they are ieee 745 single precision float values ) and comparing them to check if they are equal using following snippet,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    //a = 0x3f99999a ;
    //b = 0x3fa66666 ;
    a = 0xfa98 ;
    b = 0x65cc ;
    printf("Comparison is %d\n",((*(float*)&(a))==(*(float*)&(b))));
    printf("Numbers are a= %f and b = %f \n",(*(float*)&(a)),(*(float*)&(b)));
}
```

Following snippet was ran on 2 different platforms and both are giving different results ( one correct and other wrong ). No compiler optimizations.

Platform A - Xeon server ( Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E5) with fedora release 20 and gcc compiler version ( 4.8.3 ( Red Hat 4.8.3-7 ))

Output with a = 0xfa98 and b = 0x65cc is :

```
Comparison is 1       // This is clearly wrong as both numbers are unequal
Numbers are a= 0 and b = 0 // Casting it to float is causing them to 0 ??
```

Output with a = 0x3f99999a and b = 0x3fa66666 is :

```
Comparison is 0 // This is correct
Numbers are a= 1.2 and b = 1.3 // True decimal values for given 745 representation
```

Platform B - Intel i7 ( Intel (R) i7-3770) with ubuntu 14.04 and gcc compiler version ( 4.8.2 ( Ubuntu 4.8.2-19 ubuntu1 ))

Output with a = 0xfa98 and b = 0x65cc is :

```
Comparison is 0       // This is correct !!
Numbers are a= 0 and b = 0 // Still  0 because numbers are subnormal
```

Output with a = 0x3f99999a and b = 0x3fa66666 is :

```
Comparison is 0 // This is correct
Numbers are a= 1.2 and b = 1.3 // True decimal values for given 745 representation
```

So my question is why Platform A is producing wrong result for floating comparison . 1st set of values are subnormal and are very small in decimal representation but is definitely not equal . Where as the code works desirably for 2nd set of values ( large values ). Can somebody explain me this . Why platform A is not showing that values are not same where platform B does that ?

Comment: Note that `0xfa98`and `0x65cc` represent denormal numbers, but an IEEE-754-compliant FPU should still treat them as different. On a standard x86 Linux system your first example prints "Comparison is 0" for me. So, what platform are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using x86 machine with Fedora release 20 running on it.

Comment: OK, then what's the output if you replace `%f` with `%e`? I get `Numbers are a= 8.989610e-41 and b = 3.651784e-41`. Also, do you use any unusual compiler options?

Comment: My machine reads both a and b as 0.000000e+00 .  On your suggestion i tried snippet on different machine , intel xeon server with linux 14.04 and it produced right output (1) ! Does that mean my initial machine does not have ieee 745 compatible FPU ? Again , really appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: Machine A (x-86 with fedora ) - both icc and gcc gave output as 1. Machine B ( xeon with ubuntu 14.04 ) - both icc and gcc gave output as 0. No compiler options.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't `0` be the expected output? Anyway, if you're using an x86 processor, it's certainly not related to the FPU. It's unlikely, but it *might* be related to pointer aliasing. Do you get the expected output if you compile with `fno-strict-aliasing`? If not, I'm running out of ideas. But you should update your question with information about both of the platforms you tried: OS and compiler versions and output of your test program.

Comment: Sorry @nwellnhof ! There was a typo . Machine B is printing 0 ( which is the correct result ). I will update my question with details your requested.

Comment: @nwellnhof : Updated post with system info . I also tried the compiler flag fno-strict-aliasing but it didn't change results. Platform A still produces 1 for comparison , which is not correct.

Comment: @samkit -- what compiler options are you using, and are you running a 32bit or a 64bit OS? SSE(2) FP has a flag that, when set, puts it in a non-standard mode where denormals are treated as 0 instead....

Comment: @LThode : None . I am compiling code using gcc test.c -o test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was mxcsr register's DAZ bit. One machine A had it set so it was treating denormals as 0 . Where as on machine 2 DAZ was reset and hence it was normalizing it and treating denormals as different values , which resulted in comparison result as not equal. But I really appreciate all help guys :) ! Couldn't have debugged it without your help.

Comment: That will definitely cause the problem you're seeing!  Were you able to pin down the rogue operative on machine A that was setting the DAZ bit in the MXCSR?  Whoever it was definitely needs a bug report sent their way; fiddling with other people's control flags and not putting them back is quite rude!